# Get the culture Info of already formatted decimal or integer to currency

Tags: c#

How to get culture Info of already formatted decimal or integer to currency.
For Eg: Get culture info of this string €12.345,00

Comment: Although this is an interesting idea, it's not really possible. For example, Kosovo use the euro (despite not being in the EU) - there will always be an odd exception which will not allow you to recover the cultural information solely from a formatted money amount.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culture isn't part of the string representation of the number. That information is lost.

You can make some guesses, but in the end, it's best to simply include the culture information as well - either as part of your data directly, or in configuration. The main problem is that there are many overlaps between different cultures that may mean you'd mis-identify a particular value and interpret it entirely wrong. And there's no reason why a `en-US` culture couldn't use `€` in a number just because the "native currency" is `$`.